# grpc metadata not showing in http header

Tags: c++, grpc, grpc-c++

I am trying to send a grpc request from a c++ client to a server. On the way the http passes through a proxy that checks http header fields. I wanted to add a custom field `version` to be checked by that proxy.

I am adding it to the grpc context and sending the request:

```
protos::MyProtoRequest req;
protos::MyProtoResponse res;
grpc::ClientContext context;

context.AddMetadata("version", "0.1.2");
// proto_stub is a protobuf stub interface
const grpc::Status status = proto_stub->MyOperation(&context, req, &res);
```

Then inside my proxy I inspect the http header and I do not see a `version` field in it.

I once did something similar but with the name `authorization` instead of `version` and it worked. Here I am doing the same thing with another name and it fails. I am confused. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see a problem with your client API usage. Can you inspect the HTTP sent by the client by setting the env vars GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG and GRPC_TRACE=http and rerunning the client?